# php 5.4 installation on Mac OSX Lion from homebrew - mysqli extension missing

Tags: php, macos, mysqli, installation

I installed php 5.4 from [homebrew](https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php/),
and also mysql. I am using the inbuilt Apache Server with websharing.

I have phpMyAdmin installed and it tells me: the mysqli extension is missing.

I did the following steps:
in the php.ini I set:

```
extension = mysqli.so
mysqli.default_socket = "/tmp/mysql.sock"
```

Then restarted Apache.

When I check with `phpinfo()` I do not see any Mysql extension. The error in *phpMyAdmin* is still there.

I basically do not really see how I could check if Mysqli has come with my PHP install or not.

Comment: did this solve your problem? If so, can you chose my solution as the answer pls?

Answer (score 25):

You need to install php with mysql support. So if you already have php54 installed, then:

```
brew uninstall php54
```

then

```
brew install php54 --with-mysql
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent suggestion! Somehow the PHP upgrade process broke my installation, but this cleared it up. If I didn't like homebrew so much, I might have tried [this](http://php-osx.liip.ch/), which seems convenient when setting up a MAMP server for the first time.

Comment: If you need different development environments it's worth checking out Vagrant too: http://www.jasongrimes.org/2012/06/managing-lamp-environments-with-chef-vagrant-and-ec2-1-of-3/